# Unweighted, directed graph path finding (fastest?)

Tags: php, graph, routes

I'm developing a PHP class able to calculate the route from two points in a unweighted and directed graph system (for EVE Online in particular). I've never developed graph solutions, so I don't really know what's the fastest way of calculating graph paths, so I looked around on the net, even if I found nothing but math-centric discussions or too particular solutions.

My first idea was to find all the paths from node A to node B and compare their length. I later noticed that that was unnecessary, as I don't need to compare, but to find the first, shortest path.

Then I created a recursive system which implements the Deepening Depth-First Search algorithm (which I'm proposing here), but it's still too heavy for using it when the distance between the two nodes increase. I've successfully traced paths in 16 steps or less in few seconds. When it comes to search for more distant nodes, it won't finish in 90 seconds.

May you please help me finding a faster solution? I thought about creating a table containing all the distances and paths between the various nodes, but we're talking about thousand of nodes, it'd make forever to build it (and maintain it).

http://hastebin.com/tilusubeli.coffee

Class "jumps".

- The construct accepts the origin (from) and goal (to) nodes, in the form of string or intege. In the former case, it will resolve its ID (integer) and use it (method getSystemID, you can ignore it). The "jumpsTable" initialiser creates an array in this form:

`$this->jumpsTable[node_id] = array(next_node_id_1, next_node_id_2, ...)`

jumpsTable is the data representation of the graph.

- The public method "analyse" will simply call IDDFS

THE ALGORITHM:

- IDDFS calls DLS starting with a depth of 0 and continues up to (max depth) until DLS returns a valid path. In this way it won't choose between two routes of the same length, but it will choose the first.
- DLS is a recursive method and looks for its "children" nodes: if one of the children is the goal node, it returns the path, otherwise it calls itself with each child as "starting node" with a decreased value of depth. If any call of DLS returns a path, exit the cycle. If no DLS returns a path, return null.

Answer (score 0):

If you do a depth-first search, you have no guarantee the first path you find is the the shortest one. You should instead perform a [breadth-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search), since your graph is unweighted (otherwise, the standard algorithm would be [A*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm)).

However, you'll need a complete rework of your implementation, since the recursive approach is not suited for the breadth-first search. Note this is a very classic algorithm, it should be easier for you to find an existing PHP implementation such as [this one](http://java.dzone.com/articles/algorithm-week-graph-breadth) and adapt it to your own data structure.

PS: another way of dealing with your problem would be to use a [depth-first search with iterative deepening](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_deepening_depth-first_search), which is basically a depth-first search applied using a deep limit, and repeatedly applied with an increasing limit (until the targetted node is found).

PPS: if time is the main issue, be sure to check you don't process several times the same node.

PPPS: you might be interested by this question: [Given a directed graph, find out whether there is a route between two nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17735729/given-a-directed-graph-find-out-whether-there-is-a-route-between-two-nodes).