# Given a directed graph, find out whether there is a route between two nodes

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm, breadth-first-search

I'm trying to solve this problem and i'm fairly new to graphs. 
I tried BFS to figure this out but i'm not getting the right answer.

What am i doing wrong? Also, is there a better way of doing this, other than the approach i am using.

```
public static boolean isThereARoute(int[][] graph ,gNode n1 , gNode n2 ) {
    // where can we move? - anywhere where the value of x and y is 1 - else can't move
    // Start with node 1 and then traverse either BFS or DFS to see if the n2 is in the path anywhere

    // using BFS.

    //mark the ones where we can move as true
    boolean[][] canMove= new boolean[graph.length][graph[0].length]; 
    for(int i = 0;i<canMove.length;i++){
        for(int j =0;j<canMove[0].length;j++){
            if(graph[i][j]==-1){
                canMove[i][j] = false;
            }else{
                canMove[i][j] = true;
            }
        }
    }



    // create a queue
    Deque<gNode> queue = new LinkedList<gNode>();
    // insert the first node into the queue
    queue.add(n1);


    while(!queue.isEmpty()){
        gNode top = queue.poll();
        int x = top.x1;
        int y = top.y1;
        // only check the ones where we can go

        if( ( top.x1>=0 && top.x1<= graph.length-1) && (top.y1>=0 && top.y1<= (graph[0].length-1)) ){

            if(canMove[top.x1][top.y1]){

                if((top.x1 == n2.x1) && (top.y1 == n2.y1)){
                    // found our node;
                    return true;
                }

                // else haven't found any - add the nodes to the queue // allowed diagonals as well// therefore for each node 
                // there can be 8 neighbors
                queue.add(new gNode(x-1,y));
                queue.add(new gNode(x,y-1));
                queue.add(new gNode(x+1,y));
                queue.add(new gNode(x,y+1));
                queue.add(new gNode(x-1,y-1));
                queue.add(new gNode(x-1,y+1));
                queue.add(new gNode(x+1,y+1));
                queue.add(new gNode(x+1,y-1));

            }

        }

    }

    return false;
}
```

And for the check-

```
        int[][] graphD = new int[][]{

        {-1, 1,-1,-1,-1},
        {-1,-1, 1,-1,-1},
        {-1,-1, 1, 1,-1},
        {-1,-1,-1,-1,-1},
        { 1,-1, 1,-1,-1}
    };

    ArrayList<gNode> nodes = new ArrayList<gNode>();
    nodes.add(new gNode(0,0));//node A
    nodes.add(new gNode(1,1)); // node B
    nodes.add(new gNode(2,2)); // node C
    nodes.add(new gNode(3,3)); // node D
    nodes.add(new gNode(4,4)); // node E

    /**
     *  A->b
     * B->C
     * C->C
     * C->D
     * E-A
     * 
     */ 

    System.out.println(" is A -B connected?"+isThereARoute(graphD, nodes.get(0), nodes.get(1)));
    System.out.println(" is A -D connected?"+isThereARoute(graphD, nodes.get(0), nodes.get(3)));
    System.out.println(" is C -A connected?"+isThereARoute(graphD, nodes.get(3), nodes.get(0)));
    System.out.println(" is A -E connected?"+isThereARoute(graphD, nodes.get(0), nodes.get(4)));
    System.out.println(" is C -C connected?"+isThereARoute(graphD, nodes.get(2), nodes.get(2)));
```

Comment: I would say that BFS is the right algorithm to apply here, so you probably just have a bug in your BFS code. This is a good opportunity for you to learn how to debug!

Comment: @DaoWen: Correct. Thanks. @12rad: be careful about negative indexed cells. what will this line do `queue.add(new gNode(x-1,y));` when  x=0 and y = 10?

Comment: @Fallen - It won't do anything when he _polls_ it because he filters out bad coordinates just after polling (see the condition just after the comment "// only check the ones where we can go").

Comment: it won't do anything cause of ( ( top.x1>=0 && top.x1<= graph.length-1) && (top.y1>=0 && top.y1<= (graph[0].length-1)) )

Comment: so if I want to go from `(0,2)` to `(0,4)` where all cells are marked with `1`, I can't?

Comment: I think i know what my problem is. I don't know how to solve it though. The first time for boolean canMove[][] for all values (-1) i add false - so it can't move there. But in my method, when i am asking it to see if A(0,0) is connected to B(1,1) - the value of canMove[1][1] is false.

Comment: So, it won't ever go there. But the reason it's graph[1][1] is -1 is to signify that B is NOT connected to A BUT A is connected to B. Since it's a directed graph.

Comment: @12ad - Why do your gNodes have 2 numbers (x and y)? If `graphD` is an [adjacency matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix) (which I believe it is), then you should only need 1 number to identify a node. If you need 2 numbers then you're going to need a more complex adjacency matrix (more dimensions). Basically, I think you need to change your `gNode` to be a single index/number and re-think your BFS algorithm based on that change.

Comment: @DaoWen : I don't understand, how will i represent the node then? it has be x, y in a matrix.

Comment: @12rad - Nope, that's not how an [adjacency matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix) works. The adjacency matrix entries describe _edges_, not _nodes_. Node **A** is just 0, not (0,0). The value at (0,0) says ***A** is not connected to **A***. You should go look at that wikipedia article and see if that helps.

Comment: Okay, so i see what the problem is. I had it completely wrong. I should start with a node, - calculate all it's neighbours(including diagonals)- check to see if an edge between the neighbour is allowed, if so, all more of the neighbours - till i find my dst node?But how do i find my if i've reached my dst node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that BFS is the right algorithm to apply here, so it's just a problem with  your BFS code. It looks like you're confused about how graphs are represented in an [Adjacency Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix).

```
            if((top.x1 == n2.x1) && (top.y1 == n2.y1)){
                // found our node;
                return true;
            }
```

This is checking if a specific entry in the adjacency matrix (an edge) has been reached, but you're just supposed to be checking if a given node is reachable.

You should change your `gNode` representation to use a single index (or just drop it and use an `int` instead), and do your BFS from the first node based off the adjacency matrix values.

If you need some additional help with understanding the algorithm / data structures, this page seems like a good reference: [Adjacency matrices, BFS, DFS](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs.cmu.edu/academic/class/15211/fall.97/www/recitations/rec1112).

Comment: Okay, so i see what the problem is. I had it completely wrong. I should start with a node, - calculate all it's neighbours(including diagonals)- check to see if an edge between the neighbour is allowed, if so, all more of the neighbours - till i find my dst node?But how do i find my if i've reached my dst node?

Comment: @12rad - Since you use the phrase "including the diagonals" it sounds like you still don't understand how the adjacency matrix works. If you start at node **A**, then you read all the entries in row 0 of your matrix to find its neighbors. If you start at node **B**, then you read all the entries in row 1 of your matrix to find its neighbors. For example, the 1 at `graphD[0][1]` means there is an edge from **A** to **B** (because row 0 means "start at node **A**", and column 1 means "end at node **B**").

Answer (score 1):

I'm not good at debugging more than 10-20 lines of code if I'm not really familiar with the language.  However, I can tell you that there is a better overall approach to tell if there is a path between two nodes x and y, instead of just BFS or DFS starting from x.  Namely, you can do BFS starting from x in the forward direction, and simultaneously do BFS from y in the reverse direction.  I.e. starting with k=1, you find all vertices you can reach moving forward from x using a path of <= k edges, and you find all vertices you can reach moving reverse-direction from y using <= k edges, and you apply basic BFS principle to increase k by 1.  For each k, you hash the vertices you can reach from x, and hash the vertices you can reach from y, and if you get a match w between the two sets then w is a midpoint in a path from x to y, so a path exists.  The reason why this is preferable to BFS starting from x is that if your path from x to y has length K, then BFS starting at x will find all nodes reachable in K steps, which may be a huge set (worst-case exponential in K).  But if you do it the way I proposed, then you can terminate when you reach k >= K/2, and the 2 sets of vertices reachable in K/2 steps will often be much smaller than a set of vertices reachable in K steps.  So, when a path exists, you will typically find it much faster the way I proposed.

Comment: This is not faster _in general_, just in many cases. It's easy to build a counter-example where this is actually slower. For example, it would be slower on this graph when searching for a path from **A** to **X**: https://creately.com/diagram/hjamzsbu2/if3TDTZRdgtWzDP58PU1TJ8DIg%3D

Comment: Note I said "typically find it much faster".  Obviously you can construct a graph where there is just one possible path from x, which happens to pass through y.  Yet there could be many other paths that reach y.  The point is that the WORST-CASE complexity of my proposed approach is provably better than worst-case complexity of just doing BFS starting at x, assuming that there is a path from x to y of length K, and assuming a bound on vertex degree.

Comment: OK, that's true. However, he doesn't have any bounds on _K_, so the worst case complexity of your algorithm is still the same in this case, right?

Comment: Indeed.  :)  Both approaches could end up basically passing through all vertices.

Answer (score -1):

Approach to this can be.

```
1. BFS (most simple and efficient too)
2. Transitive closure (found using Floyd-Warshall algorithm).
```